# how can I download Image array as zip file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, download, zip

There is a Image array which name is "images" and there are 50 pictures in that array. How can I download that array as .zip file in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [Image.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) method to save your image to a memory stream
2. Use the [ZipFile Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) **or** the [Ionic.Zip library](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to create a Zip with these image streams.
3. Make a controller action, and return that zip file as a [FileResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx).  You can use the [Controller.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx) method to help you out.